# Cómo modificar datos del JSON desde PHP?

Tags: php, json

Resulta que estoy intentado hacer una especie de panel, donde pueda añadir datos y registros a una base en json desde un script o página en php. Logré hacer la base para añadir y eliminar los datos del jsón por categoria con id's, tengo problemas al momento de hacer el script para modificar los datos del json desde php.
Tengo una base hecha en PHP donde extrae los datos del JSON en un formulario de texto para modificarlo, pero no logro encontrar el error que no permite modificar los datos del JSON, al momento de pulsar sobre el botón de enviar o editar simplemente no realiza ninguna acción.

```
"playlist": {
"Eventos": [
{
"GRUPO": "Eventos",
"IMG": "img",
"CANAL": "canal",
"ID": "id",
"TV": "tv",
"URL": "url"
}
],
"Infantil": [
{
"GRUPO": "Infantil",
"IMG": "img",
"CANAL": "canal",
"ID": "id",
"TV": "tv",
"URL": "url"
}
]
}
}
```

El código hecho en PHP funcionando así: edit.php?categoria=Eventos&id=1

````
$categoria = $_GET['categoria'];
if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $id = (int) $_GET["id"];
    $getfile = file_get_contents('test.json');
    $jsonfile = json_decode($getfile, true);
    $jsonfile = $jsonfile["playlist"]["$categoria"];
    $jsonfile = $jsonfile[$id];
}

if (isset($_POST["id"])) {
    $id = (int) $_POST["id"];
    $getfile = file_get_contents('test.json');
    $all = json_decode($getfile, true);
    $jsonfile = $all["playlist"]["$categoria"];
    $jsonfile = $jsonfile[$id];

    $post["GRUPO"] = isset($_POST["GRUPO"]) ? $_POST["GRUPO"] : "";
    $post["IMG"] = isset($_POST["IMG"]) ? $_POST["IMG"] : "";
    $post["CANAL"] = isset($_POST["CANAL"]) ? $_POST["CANAL"] : "";
    $post["ID"] = isset($_POST["ID"]) ? $_POST["ID"] : "";
    $post["TV"] = isset($_POST["TV"]) ? $_POST["TV"] : "";
    $post["URL"] = isset($_POST["URL"]) ? $_POST["URL"] : "";



    if ($jsonfile) {
        unset($all["playlist"]["$categoria"][$id]);
        $all["playlist"]["$categoria"][$id] = $post;
        $all["playlist"]["$categoria"] = array_values($all["playlist"]["$categoria"]);
        file_put_contents("test.json", json_encode($all));
    }
    header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
<?php if (isset($_GET["id"])): ?>
    <form action="edit.php" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id ?>" name="id"/>
<select name="GRUPO">
    <option value="Eventos">Eventos</option>
    <option value="Infantil">Infantil</option>
</select>
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $jsonfile["IMG"] ?>" name="IMG"/>
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $jsonfile["CANAL"] ?>" name="CANAL"/>
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $jsonfile["ID"] ?>" name="ID"/>
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $jsonfile["TV"] ?>" name="TV"/>
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $jsonfile["URL"] ?>" name="URL"/>
        <input type="submit" id="enviar" value="Editar"/>
    </form>
<?php endif; ?>```
````

Comment: Ya validaste que si esté entrando al `if` del `$POST`? Porque estás usando `unset` en el elemento? porque no lo reemplazas y ya?

Comment: Cuando dices que no realiza ninguna acción... ¿a que te refieres?  A mi tu código me funciona (bueno, poniendo la llave de inicio en el json que te has olvidado en la pregunta), aunque después de la edición se quiere ir al index.php por el location que le pones, pero el json se modifica (si tiene los permisos adecuados de escritura) (y editando el id 0, pues no hay id 1 en Eventos)

Comment: Qué raro eso que me dices @masterguru, tal cual el código que puse en la pregunta lo tengo puesto y al modificar los datos y enviar en mi caso no genera cambios al json, pero no creo que sea problema de escritura ya que estuve haciendo pruebas sin "categorias" es decir directamente cambios en la array playlist y pude modificar sin problemas. Al incluirle ["playlist"]["$categoria"] al código como que algo se rompió.

Comment: Bueno, es que cambie el `action="edit.php"` por `action=""` para que me respetara los parámetros del get, porque sino da error en la primera linea porque no compruebas si existe o no ese get:  `$categoria = $_GET['categoria'];`.  Pero bueno, lo he hecho solo para saltarme ese error y así forzar entrar en el POST después para ver si lo modificaba. Eso debes replantearlo mejor.

Comment: Genial @masterguru! Gracias a tu respuesta pude replantearme mejor ese error, ahora está solucionado!